# python / ortools / cpsolver - if z is between x and y, a = b

Tags: python, or-tools

Using ortools/CPSolver in python, I'm trying to model the following with booleans and constraints:

**If z is between 5 and 10 then a is equal to 20**

I've tried using bools like this:

```
newboolvar(b1)
newboolvar(b2)

1 - add(z>=5).onlyenforceif(b1)
    add(z<5).onlyenforceif(b1).Not()
2 - add(z<=10).onlyenforceif(b2)
    add(z>10).onlyenforceif(b2).Not()
3 - (a==20).onlyenforceif(b1 & b2)
```

But you cant do & on a boolvar/intvar, so the 3rd step wont work

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can also use 1 boolean and addlinearexpressionindomain, otherwise just do `OnlyEnforceIf([b1, b2])`

Comment: of course!! - that's so simple and obvious now you mention it, thanks :) 

Not sure I follow your first suggestion on addLinearExpressionInDomain - can you give me an example please? Is there any benefit of using one over the other?